# UIWebView vs. WebKit for simple HTML

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit

For simple things like terms and conditions and "about" text that is simple-formatted HTML, should I use UIWebView or WKWebView?  Not sure I fully understand when to use what.
Im targeting iOS8+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WKWebView` rendering performance is noticeable in WebGL games and something that runs complex JavaScript algorithms, if you are using webview to load a simple html or website, you can just use `UIWebView`.

Here is a test iOS app that can be used to open any website using either `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` and you can compare performance, and then decide on whether to use `WKWebView` or `UIWebView`:

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id928647773?mt=8&at=10ltWQ

Comment: Thanks Krisrak!  Do we know if Apple intends to keep UIWebView around for awhile or move completely to WKWebView... not sure why we both?

Comment: my guess is it will be around for a while, even if they deprecate it, usually it will be around for next 2 versions of iOS, also upgrading to WKWebView is not difficult, most methods are similar.